# Generated sha1 key in PBKDF2 Python do not match in .NET Rfc2898

Tags: python, c#, encryption, aes, pbkdf2

I have a python code that generates a PBKDF2 sha1 hash of a password using the `hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac` method. Then I use that password digest in a `dotnet framework 4.5` program to verify it against the same password. The C# program returns false which suggests that the hash produced from the python program is incorrect.

The key is in this format: `#iterations|salt|key`.
Then, I take that key and I try to verify it using a dotnet framework app using via method:

```cs
public static bool IsValid(string testPassword, string originalDelimitedHash)
{
    //extract original values from delimited hash text
    var originalHashParts = originalDelimitedHash.Split('|');
    var origIterations = Int32.Parse(originalHashParts[0]);
    var origSalt = Convert.FromBase64String(originalHashParts[1]);
    var originalHash = originalHashParts[2];

    //generate hash from test password and original salt and iterations
    var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(testPassword, origSalt, origIterations, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1);
    byte[] testHash = pbkdf2.GetBytes(20);

    var hashStr = Convert.ToBase64String(testHash);
    if (hashStr == originalHash)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

my python program:

```py
from hashlib import pbkdf2_hmac
from base64 import b64encode
from os import urandom

def generate_password_hash(password:string):
    encodedPass = password.encode('utf8')

    random_bytes = urandom(20)

    salt = b64encode(random_bytes)
    iterations = 5000
    key = pbkdf2_hmac('sha1', encodedPass, salt, iterations, dklen=20)

    result = f'{iterations}|{salt.decode("utf-8")}|{binascii.hexlify(key).decode("utf-8")}'

    return result
```

So if my password is `hDHzJnMg0O` the resulting digest from the above `python` method would be something like `5000|J5avBy0q5p9R/6cgxUpu6+6sW7o=|2445594504c9ffb54d1f11bbd0b385e3e37a5aca`

So if I take that and supply it to my C# `IsValid` method (see below) it returns `false` which means the passwords do not match

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var pass = "hDHzJnMg0O";

    var hash = "5000|J5avBy0q5p9R/6cgxUpu6+6sW7o=|2445594504c9ffb54d1f11bbd0b385e3e37a5aca";
    var isValid = IsValid(pass, hash); // returns False
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python code:

- uses `b64encode(random_bytes)`  as salt for the PBKDF2 call. This is rather unusual (but not a bug). Typically the raw data, i.e. `random_bytes`, is applied as salt and passed to the PBKDF2 call. With the Base64 encoding only the string would be created.
- hex encodes the key (i.e. the return value of the PBKDF2 call).

The C# code is different in these points and:

- uses the raw data (i.e. `random_bytes` from the Python side) for the PBKDF2 call, i.e. the salt from the Python side is Base64 decoded.
- Base64 encodes the key (i.e. the return value of the PBKDF2 call)

Changes in the C# code for compatibility with the Python code (of course the changes could also be made in the Python code, but the Python code seems to be the reference):

```cs
...
var origSalt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(originalHashParts[1]); // Convert.FromBase64String(originalHashParts[1]);
...
var hashStr = Convert.ToHexString(testHash); // Convert.ToBase64String(testHash);
...
```

For the latter, `Convert.ToHexString()` was used, which is available since .NET 5. For other .NET versions see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/311179/9014097).

Furthermore, since the hex encoded values are compared and the different implementations are not standardized regarding lower (e.g. `binascii.hexlify(key)`) and upper case letters (e.g. `Convert.ToHexString(testHash)`), it is more robust to convert both strings uniformly, e.g.:

```cs
if (hashStr.ToUpper() == originalHash.ToUpper())
    return true;
```

With these changes, validation with the C# code works.

---

Edit (with regard to the change in the Python code addressed in the comment):

If in the Python code `random_bytes` is used as salt and the salt is Base64 encoded for concatenation, then in the C# code the Base64 encoded salt must be Base64 decoded again (as in the original C# code).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and taking the time to go through my code. However, after I applied the suggested changes, the C# code is still unable to verify the python-produced key digest correctly. 

Note: I applied to 3 C# code modifications you have listed in the code snippets above 
In the python code I am passing the raw salt to the PBKDF2 call and only encoding it when generating the string (i.e. b64encode(salt).decode("utf-8"))

Comment: Regarding the salt there is probably a misunderstanding. Usually the binary data i.e. `random_bytes` is the salt and passed to the PBKDF2 call, while you use `b64encode(random_bytes)` as salt and pass it to the PBKDF2 call. This is rather unusual, but not a bug.

Comment: Thank you for providing a bit more feedback and also the link to a live compiler. I did run the C# code there with the hash I provided and it, indeed, returns `true`. 

However, when I generate another hash from my python side and supply that to the online compiler it fails. I am not sure what is happening. The hash I used this time is `5000|tMZlHsdMWtafZ6BUtpNsBt9j8LM=|dc1ee150fbb52eb8bfdc42a237ad3c0766447444`

The python function I used can be found here: https://paste-bin.xyz/71721

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev - OK I just see that you changed the Python function, then of course you have to change the C# side accordingly!

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev - For this change in the C# code the salt must be Base64 decoded - as in the original code: `var origSalt = Convert.FromBase64String(originalHashParts[1])`

Comment: Thank you again for providing the updated code, I did not realise I changed the code, apologies. That worked fine! Appreciate the time you spend working on my issue!